# Angular js: what is the difference between $http and $resource

Tags: angularjs

I need to better understand the difference between $http and $resource and when to use each

Comment: I know that basically $http is a wrapper for xmlHTTPRequest (aka AJAX) like jQuery's $ajax and that $resource is supposed to be more REST-specific but I don't really get how...

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS $http and $resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$resource is built on top of $http.

$http is normal ajax, it can be used for any form of web service.

$resource is specifically for RESTful service.

More details on this

[AngularJS $http and $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource)

Answer (score 9):

From the `$resource` docs:

> A factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with
>   RESTful server-side data sources.
>
> The returned resource object has action methods which provide
>   high-level behaviors without the need to interact with the low level
>   $http service.

`$resource` is a higher level service than `$http`.