# Make Synchronous call with $resource in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I am new to `angularjs`.After creating some projects with restful web service I got stuck at some point.So please help to me to solve that issues.
I have read the difference between `$resource` and `$http` from [AngularJs $resource vs $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897289/angular-js-what-is-the-difference-between-http-and-resource)

My issue is that as I am using `$resource` the data come asynchronously 
e.g. if I am saving any data and transfer to detail page that data I got is not updated and if I will wait for some time than I will get newly data.

So I need to go on `$http` or is there any other way to make call synchronously.
I have also try with `$promise` but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Code?  Using promises should be a viable way to solve it.

Comment: I doubt the answer is to do a sync request - can you post your code in question?

Comment: You don't want synchronous data, your UI will be stuck and [it's deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()).

Comment: Do all your manipulation part inside the promise returned by the API i.e in success response

Answer (score 4):

This is how I use $resource

in controller:

```
var promise = Service.queryItem();
    promise.then(function(response){

        // just adding my response items to an array
        angular.forEach(response, function(item){
            $scope.items.push(item);
        });

    }, function(reason){
        console.log(reason);
});
```

In service

```
this.queryItem = function (){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        // deferred.notify('Saving data..');
        var items = Items.query({},function() {
            deferred.resolve(items.d.results);
        }, function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

In $resource factory:

```
// just a snippet from my factory
query: {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    url: "RequestURL"
},
```

As some comments stated, the use of `promise` will make it run in the desired order , as you can see I do my forEach after `.then`