# What's wrong with this service in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Please I have two questions , For huge applications, Angularjs , Is it a good solution in term of cpu usage?

What is wrong with my angular code?

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.service('server', function (url){
    this.get = function ($http){
    return $http.get(url);
    };        
});



myapp.controller('myctrl' , function($scope,server){

    setInterval(function(){

        $scope.r= server.get('response.js');

    },1000);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced your `$http` dependency:

```
myapp.service('server', function (url){
    this.get = function ($http){
        return $http.get(url);
    };        
});
```

Should be

```
myapp.service('server', function ($http){
    this.get = function (url){
        return $http.get(url);
    };        
});
```

Also, you are using the return value of `$http.get()` as if you are donig a [`$resource.get()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource). This won't work for array results. Consider using `$resource` instead:

```
return $resource(url).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

[$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) returns a promise. You will have use a callback to get the result:

```
server.get('response.js').success(function(data){
    $scope.r = data;
});
```

Comment: Objects are still unwrapped by AngularJS. As long as it is not an array that should work.