# Angular resource and $http.put

Tags: angularjs

What's the difference between using $resource to make a put request and using $http.put to make a put request? Does it make any difference in the speed or performance?

Comment: Not really speed wise, but make the things more testable...FYI its not about the speed its about the code separation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check  [Answers in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource) stackoverflow thread

$resource is further high-level abstraction of $http. I don't think $resource added significant performance burden on top of $http to get the high-level API .