# how to convert $resource to $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-service

How can my use of `$resource` be converted to instead leverage the raw `$http` service? And what exactly does `$resource` do that `$http` does not?

```
return $resource(API_LINK+'/api/users/', {
   id: '@_id'
 },
 {
   changePassword: {
     method: 'PUT',
     params: {
       controller:'password'
     }
   },
   get: {
     method: 'GET',
     params: {
       id:'me'
     }
   })
```

Comment: refer this question for difference between $http and $resources. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource

Comment: get : function () {
      $http.get(API_LINK + '/api/users/', {id:'me',controller:'password'})
       .success(function (response) {
         console.log('response', response);
         //defer.resolve(response);
       })
       .error(function (err) {
         console.log('err', err);
        // defer.reject(err);
       });
       //return defer.promise;
    }

Comment: I did this and api works fine but giving one error, error is:

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Comment: Can you elaborate what you had done? Because above you passed two parameter in get method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$resource` is simply an abstraction over `$http` with the idea that the API is convenient to use for RESTful endpoints. There is nothing `$resource` can do that can not be written using `$http`. A way to write the above in a factory leveraging `$http` may include...

```
// assumption that API_LINK is an injectable constant
.factory('MyService', function(API_LINK, $http) {

    function changePassword(params) {
        return $http.put(API_LINK +'/api/users/', params);
    }

    function get(id) {
        return $http.get(API_LINK +'/api/users?id=' + id);
    }

    return {
        changePassword: changePassword,
        get: get
    }
});
```

with the following usage...

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, MyService) {

    MyService.get('me').then(function(response) {
        // ...
    });

    MyService.changePassword({ controller: 'password' }).then(function(response) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

If you need to take total control of your factory functions with involved promise resolution, I would suggest checking out the [AngularJS $q API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: what about id:@_id? where should i put it

Answer (score 0):

we can also do with another way like this:

```
get: function() {
    var id = 'me';
    $http.get(API_LINK + '/api/users/' + id )
      .success(function(response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        defer.reject(err);
      });
    return defer.promise;
  },

  changePassword: function() {
    $http.put(API_LINK + '/api/users/', {controller:'password'} )
      .success(function(response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        defer.reject(err);
      });

    return defer.promise;
  }
```