# How would $resource fit into the Angular Style Guide?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

We will soon be refactoring our code against the [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). The guide itself is great (and can be found slightly modified all over the interwebs), but no one mentions how $resource fits into a factory, or any reasons why it might have been left out. One guide says to [use $resource over $http where you can](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide#others), but then doesn't add it into their style for factories :/.

I remember reading in lots of places that $resource was better and that's why I started to use it, but now I'm forgetting why and wondering if that is still true - especially given the resource object at the bottom of this post. There are some opinions ([Papas own](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/501), and [again](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/86)) about $resource (not?) being great, but that's another issue that I'm re-checking.

**So, assuming we want to use $resource and given this sample code below, where does $resource fit in so that it adheres to the reasoning behind the styles in the guide?** Also, if your answer is "It doesn't. The style [subtly] recommends $http because bla, bla and bla.", then that would be a useful as well.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .factory('oneService', oneService);

    predicateService.$inject = ['twoService', 'anotherService'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function oneService(twoService, anotherService) {
        var service = {
            doSomething: doSomething,
            etc: etc
        };

        // pos 1 (it really only works here but can be LONG)
        // var fancyResource = $resource('/path/to/thing', '...');

        // Ideally, this should be kept close to the top, right?
        return service;

        // pos 2 (here or below ////// is cleaner, but doesn't work)
        // var fancyResource = $resource('/path/to/thing', '...');

        ////////////////

        function doSomething() {}

        // rest of functions here etc...
    }
})();
```

Now, the only place that we use $resource (and maybe this is also incorrect) is within methods like `doSomething()`. At various points in the past, and even in various places in our code today, `fancyResource` is made public by the service and used directly from the controller: `oneService.fancyResource.get()`. I'm thinking this may be the intended use for `$resource`, but I'm not sure anymore.

Also, consider that one service might be quite large (never mind the fact that some of this should/could be broken into multiple resources; let's just pretend a resource object this size is likely and many verbs are needed):

```
var userResource = $resource(baseApiPath + 'users', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: utilityService.getHeaders('sampling'),
        isArray: true,
        transformResponse: function(response){
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response.result){
                return response.result.users;
            }
            return response;
        }
    },
    getUserDetails: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseApiPath+'users/:userId',
        params: {
            userId: '@userId'
        },
        headers: utilityService.getHeaders('sampling'),
        transformResponse: function(response){
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response.result){
                return response.result.user;
            }
            return response;
        }
    },
    getUserByRole: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseApiPath+'users/roles/:roleId',
        params: {
            roleId: '@roleId'
        },
        headers: utilityService.getHeaders('sampling'),
    },
    getLoggedInUserData: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseApiPath + 'users/userData',
        headers: utilityService.getHeaders('sampling'),
    },
    getGrantedAuth: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseApiPath+'users/applicationPermissions/userId/:userId/:applicationId/',
        params: {
            applicationId: '@applicationId',
            userId: '@userId'
        },
        headers: utilityService.getHeaders('sampling'),
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35212885/2800116) is helping me figure why $resource might just be plain overkill. Thinking on it, I don't even use the save/update/delete() methods it provides, and am constantly redoing the path. The last line is especially key. Regardless, I'd still like to know where a $resource object goes in the above style of factory.

Comment: seems you are overthinking things as well as creating a significant amount of code duplication in your current approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I've found my answer based on a few thoughts.

Firstly, I now realize that using a $resource like this is totally incorrect for two reasons. The first is that I was creating additional actions that required their own unique path. The whole point of a $resource is to make doing `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` on a **single** REST resource easier. I was basically combining my resources because they appeared to be unified. For example, `/users` and `/users/roles/:roleId` should have been two different resources (and probably put into two different services to maintain the single responsibility style).

The second way I was using $resource wrong is actually because I wasn't really using the `query`, `save`, or `delete` methods that it supplies me with. I would just create another custom action for whatever I wanted to do. Sometimes this also included a unique URL like `/users/:userId/delete`, and that was because the API wasn't always a REST API. $resource is specifically designed for REST compliant APIs. Because it wraps $http and it can pass parameters to it, it's easy to fall into this trap. $resource is not intended to be a configuration for multiple $http uses.

**So, now with that out of the way, here is how I would propose to include $resource into a factory, and still follow the style guide.**

First, $resource should only be used with a true REST API. One where you only have/need one path, and only/mostly HTTP methods are used to interact with it. Also, because a factory is intended to represent and manage one kind of 'thing', interacting with the 'thing API', there should really only be one $resource per service. Extending the example, there would be a users service and a roles service; each with one $resource. There could then be another userRoleService that utilizes them both, and doesn't actually do any $resource stuff on its own. Something like that, anyway.

This being the case, the $resource config would actually be significantly shorter than what I was originally posting. Since it's smaller, we can treat it more like a variable declaration and put it above the service object that we create.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .factory('oneService', oneService);

    predicateService.$inject = ['anotherService', '$resource'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function oneService(anotherService, $resource) {

        // this resource is unlikely to get longer than this
        var userResource = $resource('http://api.com/users/:userId', {
            userId: '@userId'
        });

        // and we're still able to see all bindables at the top
        var service = {
            doSomething: doSomething,
            etc: etc
        };
        return service;

        ////////////////

        function doSomething() {
            // and in a service method, we can use the resource like this,
            userResource.query().$promise
            .then(function(response){...})
        }

        function doSomethingElse() {
            // or we could use the $resource in a way that would make
            // chainable with another .then() in the calling method.
            var load = userResource.query();

            // do some internal stuff when we get the response
            load.$promise
            .then(function(response){...});

            // then return the $resource object, or load.$promise
            // so that another .then can be chained afterwards.
            return load;
        }

        // rest of functions here etc...
    }
})();
```

Anyway, that's the answer that I came up with. I hope this helps some of you who came here looking for what I was looking for (and couldn't easily find).