# add config in angular resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http-auth

I am using [http-auth-interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) for authentication. In http-auth-interceptor, I use the following way to login:

```
        var data = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(user.userId) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(user.password);
        $http.post('api/authenticate', data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            ignoreAuthModule: 'ignoreAuthModule'
        })
```

`ignoreAuthModule` is used to tell `ignoreAuthModule` that this login method will be ignored by the auth interceptor.

Now, I have some request with $resource, like:

```
.factory('SomeDataService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/some/data', {}, {
       'get': { method: 'GET'}
    });
})
```

I want `SomeDataService.get()` is also ignored by the auth interceptors, because I need to control the 401 error by myself.

So, my question is, is there any way for ngResource that I can set config like that in $http.

[update based on comment]
I have listened the `login-required` event:

```
    $rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function (rejection) {
        $log.log(rejection);
        // I need to get the request url and for some specific url, need to do something.
        $rootScope.loginPopup();
    });
```

But the 'rejection' parameter has no context data of request I need. I need to get the request url and check, for some specified url, I need to do something.

Comment: You are listening to "event:auth-loginRequired", right? Why not do a check there where it comes from and act accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the document of ngResource, I got the solution as below:

```
.factory('SomeDataService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/some/data', {}, {
       'get': { method: 'GET', ignoreAuthModule: 'ignoreAuthModule'}
    });
})
```

Just add the config item as above. It will be equivalent ad:

```
$http.post('api/some/data', data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        ignoreAuthModule: 'ignoreAuthModule'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

ngResource module is build on top of $http.Hence it is not possible to configure all the stuffs you can do with $http in $resource.I think the below link will be guide you to have a clear understanding on [$http and $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource)