# JHipster : when to use $http and when to use $resource

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I'm exploring how jhipster manipulates data. I have found  `$http.get()` in `getProfileInfo` method in `ProfileService` Service whitch interacting restful `api`  :

```
function getProfileInfo() {
            if (!angular.isDefined(dataPromise)) {
                dataPromise = $http.get('api/profile-info').then(function(result) {
                    if (result.data.activeProfiles) {
                        var response = {};
                        response.activeProfiles = result.data.activeProfiles;
                        response.ribbonEnv = result.data.ribbonEnv;
                        response.inProduction = result.data.activeProfiles.indexOf("prod") !== -1;
                        response.swaggerDisabled = result.data.activeProfiles.indexOf("no-swagger") !== -1;
                        return response;
                    }
                });
            }
            return dataPromise;
        }
```

and some where i have found `$resouce()` manipulating `GET` method. for example in `BankAccount` factory :

```
var resourceUrl =  'api/bank-accounts/:id';
```

I searched for when to use `$http` and when to use `$resource` and i found this :

[AngularJS $http and $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource)

why `hipster` is not following `consistent` way of interacting API and manipulating data!!?

so `jhipster`, when to use `$http` and when to use `$resource` in services??

Comment: In your example, both are equivalent.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes they are using same HTTP method. they use GET. functionality is ok but why jhipster not using resource even using $resource is efficient interacting API's?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `$resource` when requesting a RESTful endpoint, for example for an entity. `$resource` provides basic REST operations easily whereas `$http` is more specific.

For profile we only need to GET `/profile-infos` so it's useless to use `$resource` because we'll never need to call POST or DELETE on that URL.

Answer (score 1):

$http will fetch you the entire page or complete set of data from a given URL whereas $resouce uses http but will help you to fetch a specific object or set of data.
$resource is fast and we use it when we need to increase the speed of our transaction.
$http is used when we are concerned with the time.

Comment: Have you made some measurements? I don't think few mili seconds in browser matter.

Comment: Yes it does matter when thousands of people are accessing a common page and they need it quick. $resource improves performance and is capable of providing loose coupling.