# how can I construct .post query based on checkboxes clicked on page with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html form:

```
<form name="queryForm" class="form-inline text-center">
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one" ng-model="formData.one" ng-true-value="'one'" ng-init="formData.one='one'">
        One
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two" ng-model="formData.two" ng-true-value="'two'" ng-init="formData.two='two'">
        Two
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three" ng-model="formData.three" ng-true-value="'three'" ng-init="formData.three='three'">
        Three
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-top:24px;margin-left:8px" ng-click="queryNumbers()">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

and it shows 3 checkboxes on my page and a button. I want to construct a `.post` query to my webservice based on the values user selects. I wrote a function for that:

```
$scope.queryUsers = function(){

    var one = $scope.formData.one;
    var two = $scope.formData.two;
    var three = $scope.formData.three;

    var params = [];

    if(one){

    }
    if(two){

    }
    if(three){

    }

    //here I want to create a .post query
};
```

As for now, I have my webservice ready, it takes the json in the following format:

```
"one":"true" //can be false
"two":"true" //can be false
"three":"true" //can be false
```

I want to create a `params` array and create post query - how can I fill this array with `true` or `false` values for each number based on the checkboxs' values?

Comment: can you make an example of your array ideal format?

Answer (score 1):

official doc 
    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Working plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/D7AV2DavhvNny9rppy4r?p=preview

You have to do inject '$http' in your controller depence :

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope','$http',  function($scope,$http) {
```

then :
JS

```
$scope.queryUsers = function() {
    console.clear();
    var one = $scope.formData.one;
    var two = $scope.formData.two;
    var three = $scope.formData.three;

    //here I want to create a .post query

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'path/to/service', // put your url her
      data: {
        "one": one,
        "two": two,
        "three": three
      }

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // success 
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

  };
```

html :

```
<form name="queryForm" class="form-inline text-center">
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one" ng-model="formData.one" ng-init="formData.one=false">
        One
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two" ng-model="formData.two" ng-init="formData.two=false">
        Two
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three" ng-model="formData.three" ng-init="formData.three=false">
        Three
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-top:24px;margin-left:8px" ng-click="queryUsers()">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @AlainIb, and one more thing - can you tell me how I could construct the array instead of passing arguments directly? I mean - I need to create an array first and then - in the `.post` query refer to each element of that array

Comment: give the array you want. you say you want a json with bool value ?

Comment: an array like `[ ]` or associative array like `{ }` . my solution already send an associative array

Comment: i update answer, look at the plunkr, open console ( f12 ) and click on refresh button in your form, look at the POST made

Comment: hm with that approach I'm getting error `$http(...).then(...).error is not a function`, do you know why it might be a problem?

Comment: did you inject $http in your controller like this `myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope','$http',  function($scope,$http) {`

Answer (score 1):

1)You need to create an associative array,something like this:

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.queryNumbers = function(){
    var one = $scope.formData.one;
    var two = $scope.formData.two;
    var three = $scope.formData.three;

    var params = {};
    params["one"]=one!='one';
    params["two"]=two!='two';
    params["three"]=three!='three';
    console.log(params);
};
})
```

```css
.done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <form name="queryForm" class="form-inline text-center">
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one" ng-model="formData.one" ng-true-value="'one'" ng-init="formData.one='one'">
        One
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two" ng-model="formData.two" ng-true-value="'two'" ng-init="formData.two='two'">
        Two
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three" ng-model="formData.three" ng-true-value="'three'" ng-init="formData.three='three'">
        Three
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-top:24px;margin-left:8px" ng-click="queryNumbers()">Refresh</button>
</form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2) Don't forget to send data to server using `JSON.stringify(object)`;

> JSON.stringify function turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores it in a string.

In your case you need to use something like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'you_method_url',
  data:JSON.stringify(params)
}).then(..);
```

Comment: this is not an array, but an associative array or object . array is [ ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$http`, but if you are calling a *RESTful* API, I would suggest you to use `$resource` (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)).

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181406/angularjs-http-and-resource).

Personally, I prefer to use it inside of a service.

```
app.factory('Articles',
  ($resource) => (
    $resource(`/path/to/articles/:articleId`)
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make things a bit more generic.

First at all is bad to have the same `name` attr for multiple input elements.

```html
<form name="queryForm" class="form-inline text-center">
  <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="one" id="checkOne" value="one" ng-model="formData.one" ng-true-value="'one'" ng-init="formData.one='one'">One
  </p>
  <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="two" id="checkTwo" value="two" ng-model="formData.two" ng-true-value="'two'" ng-init="formData.two='two'">Two
  </p>
  <p class="checkbox-inline onlinecheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onlinecheckbox" name="three" id="checkThree" value="three" ng-model="formData.three" ng-true-value="'three'" ng-init="formData.three='three'">Three
  </p>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-top:24px;margin-left:8px" ng-click="queryNumbers()">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

Then you can access the form by his `name` in the angular scope and play with the inputs inside without actally know the names!

```js
var form = $scope.queryForm;
var params = [];

for (let name in form) {
  if (form.hasOwnProperty(name) && typeof form[name] === 'object' && form[name].hasOwnProperty('$modelValue')) {
    // build the array as you want here
    params.push($scope.formData[name]);
  }
}
```